# Ubuntu reboots instead of shutdown on iMac

Tags: boot, suspend, shutdown, mac, reboot

I am running Ubuntu on iMac late 2015, 21.5 inch (the 1tb hdd version) and it’s running effortlessly with just one issue,
**It reboots on a shutdown**.

(Suspend doesn’t work too, it just hangs the system or reboot sometimes but it happens to most Apple devices on linux so i let that slide)

I have tried Linux kernel 5.17 to 5.12 and lts 5.4, all of these had the same issue.

Evidently, I thought it was an ACPI issue so I turned it off with quiet splash acpi=off in the grub file but it didn’t make any difference. I have tried running XHCI > /proc/wakeup/acpi that to led too no difference

I need some guidance to how to fix this issue,
Much gratitude

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: 22.4, i have tried arch fedora 35 pop os manjaro but they all had the same result